# custom bullet points alignment on iphone chrome

Tags: ios, css, iphone

I use in a project custom bulletpoints for a unordered list.

My CSS looks like that:

```
.einleitung-txt .einleitung-bullet li::before {
content: "\2022";
color: #c6285d;
font-size: 2em;
margin-left: -20px;
line-height: 0.1em;
position: relative;
top:.22em;
display: inline-block;
width: 20px;
```

}

On every Browser and on Android it looks like that:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M63Uw.png

Well, my client use a Iphone and he show me that it looks not correct:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S34jT.jpg

Is it the top of the points? 
I use this way to show bullet points because I have more than one line of text.

Comment: Are you sure that the font in use does contain the bullet? (Otherwise the browser will choose a different font, with presumably different metrics.) Also, is the comma in the original css too, or is that just a typo here?

Comment: Ah, no the comma is not the problem. I changed my question...
Good question with the font... I use Roboto and with a MacBook the font have no problem to show the bullets.

Comment: The font shown is not the same in both screenshots.

Comment: You are right. How can I fix them?

Comment: If you know what fonts are normally installed on an iPhone, use one of those. Otherwise, you may need a `@font-face` rule.